# Windows Universal app - no "Any CPU" configuration for Windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm updating Windows Universal project that was created with

*Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 10 **Technical** Preview*

to

[Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 10 **Insider** Preview](https://dev.windows.com/en-US/downloads/windows-10-sdk):

So the solution file's changes is only *VisualStudioVersion* from *14.0.22609.0* to *14.0.22823.1*.

The project file's changes are also minor:

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10030.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.10030.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
```

to

```
 <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.10069.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
 <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.10069.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
```

The issue is that originally this universal project has been built successfully against **Any CPU** configuration, but now I'm started getting the following error:

> The processor architecture of the project being built "Any CPU" is not
>   supported by the referenced SDK "Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime,
>   Version=1.0". Please consider changing the targeted processor
>   architecture of your project (in Visual Studio this can be done
>   through the Configuration Manager) to one of the architectures
>   supported by the SDK: "x86, x64, ARM".

So the message is clear what to do, just want to confirm:

Is that really so that **Any CPU** is no longer possible for universal projects starting from "SDK for Windows 10 Insider Preview"?

**Update**

There is no AnyCPU for the newly created project as well - the default one is **x86**.

Comment: Keep in mind you are using an SDK that can and will change, bugs and all.

Comment: @SteveFerg, sure. Wondering how much it could be "by design" or just a bug.

Comment: this is surprising to me as well, kinda feels like a requirement rather than a bug.  It's this way with File new project as well, no support for Any Cpu

Comment: @Quincy, exactly! The first thing I've tried was new blank universal project and no mention of Any CPU for it as well.

Comment: **THOSE AREN'T THE ONLY CHANGES IN THE CSPROJ**  -- Please do File>New in the "RC" build, and then windiff the resulting .csproj with your existing one. You'll find you must also add <EnableDotNetNativeCompatibleProfile>true</EnableDotNetNativeCompatibleProfile>, and additionally add <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain> in each of the Release builds.

Comment: @LucianWischik, thanks for info - I guess I have opened the project settings page and just save it and mentioned options were added to the project file automatically, cause when I've checked the diff with newly created sample project some time later - there were no (major) difference between them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

And here comes the [answer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn975273.aspx#Update10CSharp):

> 2. Open your solution that contains your C# Windows Universal app. You will see that your project file (.csproj file) needs to be updated. Right-click the project file and choose to edit this file.
> 3. Find the `<PropertyGroup>` element that contains the `<TargetPlatformVersion>` ... Next, set the value of the `<Platform>` element to **x86** ...
> 4. Find `<PropertyGroup>` elements that are configured for the **AnyCPU** platform as part of the Condition attribute. Remove these elements and all of their child elements. **AnyCPU is not supported for Windows 10 apps in Visual Studio 2015 RC**.

**UPDATE 1**

From this video - [Deep Dive into XAML and .NET Universal Windows App Development](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-790), forward to **0:32:28** - it seems like there is a (small) chance to get back "Any CPU" in the release:

[image: Screenshot from Deep Dive into XAML and .NET Universal Windows App Development video]

**UPDATE 2**

One more confirmation from [Visual Studio 2015 RC fixed bugs and known issues](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025133):

> The **AnyCPU** platform configuration is not supported for Windows 10 Insider Preview applications that are built by using C# and Visual Basic. This release of Visual Studio uses the .NET Native to build Windows 10 applications. The .NET Native compiles C# and Visual Basic code to native code and is not CPU-agnostic.

So it seems to me that hope for getting back "AnyCPU" config is almost gone even for VS2015 RTM.

**UPDATE 3**

Well, [the RTM is finally here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-vs.aspx) and as expected - [no AnyCPU](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Mt148501.aspx):

> Find  elements that are configured for the AnyCPU platform as part of the Condition attribute. Remove these elements and all of their children. **AnyCPU is not supported for Windows 10 apps in Visual Studio 2015**.

Comment: Nice thanks.  We called it - AnyCPU is not supported!  Wow interesting

Comment: Will it be supported in the final VS2015?

Comment: Thx, it seems that there is still hope... :) I need AnyCPU for my library, http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com, otherwise packaging will be a pain..

Comment: It seems really odd that they would remove Any CPU as a target. :-/

Answer (score 3):

Well, **AnyCPU** is still there for **DLL** and **Windows Runtime Component** project types. The absence of AnyCPU is caused by usage of .NET Native by default for Universal Windows apps in Release configuration. As you may know, .NET Native links the app and all its dependencies into a single EXE, so that's why AnyCPU would still be there for DLLs and WinRT components.

Now I'm not sure but DevDiv guys seem to be gathering feedback about the "default-ness" of .NET Native, so AnyCPU still might return by the time or after RTM if there's enough feedback on this. Still, I believe .NET Native is worth it since you generally deploy your apps via Store anyway.

Comment: I would say that generally I deploy _my_ apps exactly via side-loading and from the Store I deploy _other people's_ apps.

Comment: But anyway it is good to have AnyCPU at least for runtime component projects.

Comment: I'm a "devdiv guy". .NET Native is mandatory for store apps. The only thing which Unni alluded to about "looking for feedback" is, if you love AnyCPU enough, then maybe we can "fake it up" -- i.e. make it so that you can select AnyCPU, and it interrogates your target device as to what architecture it is, and then implicitly picks that architecture. The app itself can never truly be AnyCPU.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Though, some criticism for Microsoft: supporting "Native" compilation doesn't really feel like a good excuse -- this is a solved problem after all (the Mac had native apps that could run on PPC and Intel for a long time; they just compiled "Fat Binaries" that contained multiple executable images compiled in to it). -- Seems like it would be **super easy** to create a windows store package that contained multiple exes, one for each platform.

Comment: I think this should have been the accepted answer and just discovered an excellent reference at: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/08/20/net-native-what-it-means-for-universal-windows-platform-uwp-developers/#6CI4LZrhQ3bdieXd.97 (I think it is possible to publish a Windows Store app with multiple EXEs, though I wish they would have got this smoother.)

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are right clicking on your project going to Properties. At the top line of "Build" under platform you have ARM, x64, x86 and All Platforms. A little further down in the "General" group box you have "Platform target" which gives you Any CPU, x86, x64, and ARM.

If you are looking at the Configuration Manager (build->Configuration Manager), you are right there is only ARM, x64, x86, new..., and edit.... If you click on New..., "Any CPU" is an option (default) you can add, and then you can go back and select it for your configuration.

Comment: Really hoped that this will work, but, unfortunately - still getting the error quoted in the question even after changing configuration everywhere to Any CPU. I suspect that the key words here will be: "... Any CPU is _not supported_ by the referenced SDK" and "...one of the architectures _supported by the SDK_: "x86, x64, ARM"".